# Using the Google Drive REST API, is it possible to retrieve multiple resources at once?

Tags: google-drive-api

In my application I would like to show the parent folder name below each file found using the list method call plus a search query.

So far I can get the id of the parent from the search result -- however I then must make individual get calls for each unique folder.

I would like to make a single call to retrieve multiple parent folder names, specified by multiple id's either through get or list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [batch the GET requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch) together so that you only need to make one HTTP round trip.

Answer (score 0):

As Jay said, you can batch the requests. An alternative technique would be to fetch all folder names and create a memory map of id -> name. Depending on how many unique folders you have, this latter approach is probably more efficient.